# Floating point exception (core dumped)

Tags: c, exception, floating-point, coredump, floating-point-exceptions

I have a long program, which consists of one header file, and two source files, in the first one I have written the implementations of the functions, and in the second one (which is my main), I call and execute them. Though, at one point I get an error message saying

> Floating point exception (core dumped)

and the program stops.

As I said there are lots of lines of code, therefore, I'm not able to post my whole source code here, though I will post the most relevant parts, and where error occurs.

My error occurs when I try to call this function (below you can find its implementation):

```
void chest_first(Complex* FFTInput, Complex* IFFTOutput, Complex* HFirst)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        HFirst[i].real = FFTInput[i].real / IFFTOutput[i].real;
        HFirst[i].imag = FFTInput[i].imag / IFFTOutput[i].imag;
    }

}
```

In this case Complex, is a type definition that I have defined.

```
typedef struct {
    int real, imag;
} Complex;
```

Here is the part from the main, where this function is called.

```
  Complex HFirst[64];

  if((strcmp(channel, "LS") == 0) || (strcmp(channel, "ls") == 0))
  {
      if(i == 1)
        chest_first(fft_input, ifft_bpsk_output, HFirst);
      .
      .
      .
  }
```

I have earlier called some other function, which put values to fft_input and ifft_bpsk_output, which are both Complex arrays with 64 elements.

Comment: `IFFTOutput[i].real` (or `.imag`) is 0. (Or `-1`, and the dividend is `INT_MIN` is another possibility on some platforms.) Confusingly, an integer division by 0 gives rise to `SIGFPE`.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, your insightful comment about the quirks of integer division and causing SIGFPE deserves an answer posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably dividing by zero or some other nonsensical number. Are you sure `real` and `imag` for `IFFTOutput[i]`  isn't zero? Print it out just before perhaps?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I completely missed it. I was dividing with 0.

Answer (score 4):

I think it could be a problem of division by 0, check your value about that.

Answer (score -1):

I was also having the same problem.It occurs due to using value greater than which your datatype can handle
for ex.
using an array of size 10^7 while you defined it as int A[10^7]
this will dumped becouz an int array cannot handle this much size..
So you have to use appropriate datatypes..
thank you
:)